# How to ask for facebook permissions when user already logged in?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I need to ask users permissions, there is no problem when he isn't logged in, i'm just using facebook login button and:

`div class=\"fb-login-button\" scope=\"user_likes,friends_likes\" onlogin=some_script`

But when the user logged in and didn't authorize the application yet, the login button shows the permissions request dialog but the onlogin script isn't running because the user is already logged in!

I still need to run this script in case the user is logged in and after that authorize the application.

What to do?

Comment: Use [`FB.login`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) for login and/or asking for additional permissions.

Comment: how do i redirect or running some script after asking for additional permissions?

Comment: Check the FB.login docs that @CBroe cites, the code you will need to run is going to be in the if response.authResponse is true.